# How to add contact without adding Phone/Mobile number?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a contact using `ContentProviderOperation` where basic idea is to create a contact which might don't have Phone or Mobile number at all but may have some other type of contact number which is adding using Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM with different label. Here is a code:

```
//ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops;

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, mobileNumber)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .build());

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                        .build());
```

and some contact type:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phoneNumber)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM )
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL, "Emergency: "+name+" "+surname+" 11111")
                            .build());
```

it don't create a main contact if both mobileNumber and phoneNumber are empty so if i provide some value of phoneNumber/mobileNumber then contact is create which containing custom contact information as well. So is there any way to create contact without Phone.TYPE_HOME/Phone.TYPE_MOBILE ?

Comment: Try to add fake number and than delete it.

Comment: Deleting a number is not possible as far i can see unless i delete a whole contact.